# How can I convert this "IMUL ecx" into c code?

Tags: c, assembly, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I'm reverting an assembly code to C. I came across a part of the code that I cannot understand.

```
 mov ecx,8A69
 mov eax,66666667
 imul ecx
 sar edx,2
 mov eax,ecx
 sar eax,1F
 sub edx,eax
 mov eax,edx
 shl eax,2
 add eax,edx
 add eax,eax
 sub ecx,eax
 mov eax,ecx
```

When passing through IMUL ECX, **"EAX = 3333863F"** and **"EDX = 375D"**.
How can I pass this to C and continue to revert this code?

Comment: That's doing signed integer division by a constant, like `x / 123` or something: [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41183935).  But both inputs are constant so it's really pointless to do at runtime.  (Note the `sar eax,31` to broadcast the sign bit to all positions as a fixup for negative; that's how you can tell it's signed.)

Comment: Looking at the answer to this question, I saw that the code tests if a number is multiple of 10. However, I have no idea how I can reach this same conclusion.

Comment: I don't know the formula for inverting a fixed-point multiplicative inverse back into the original divisor.  One simple thing would be to try it for one large dividend by single-stepping in a debugger (so you don't need to add a call to printf).  Given a dividend and quotient, you can find the divisor the code is implementing.